# Como tomar los valores del registro anterior en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito recorrer una tabla ordenada por el campo `kdx_id` el cual no se ve en la imagen, calcular y corregir los valores del campo `kdx_qtyBeforeMov` y del campo `kdx_qtyAfterMov` que es igual a `kdx_qtyBeforeMov MAS kdx_qtyIn o MENOS kdx_qtyOut` del registro anterior como lo muestra la imagen

[image: Tabla]

En el primer registro de la imagen, `kdx_qtyBeforeMov` viene de un registro anterior, `kdx_qtyAfterMov` es la resta de `3-3=0`, en siguiente registro `kdx_qtyBeforeMov = 0` que esta bien, pero en el tercer registro debería ser -3

Lo he intentado hacer con una tabla temporal en código php, pero no me da resultado, es posible hacerlo directamente en una sola consulta sql?

Comment: Sí, es posible. Para decirte cómo, necesitamos que modifiques tu pregunta añadiendo la tabla en SQL (phpmyadmin->export) y que nos indiques cómo ordenas los registros, porque no parece que tengan un id o marca temporal que permita determinar cuál va antes

Comment: la tabla esta ordenada por el campo kdx_id el cual no se ve en la imagen, pero no creo que eso sea relevante

Comment: Si te lo estoy pidiendo, igual un poco relevante sí que será :) En la respuesta te explico por qué. Modifica la pregunta añadiendo el SQL de la tabla con algún dato de ejemplo, el resultado que esperas obtener para esos datos de muestra y te digo cómo hacerlo

Comment: ordenar para obtener el registro anterior, es como MUY RELEVANTE... si no, como sabe sql cual es el registro anterior? y si pensas que sql sabe cual es el registro anterior, entonces estas equivocado...

Comment: Intuyo que este tipo de problemas no deberían ni resolverse ni reflejarse en una base de datos. ¿Acaso no es este un caso contextual, a resolver de forma dinámica, por programación, allí donde necesites ordenar esos datos? Puede que me equivoque, pues la pregunta no es clara y del contexto no nos dices nada. Un caso típico de error parecido a este es decidir guardar la edad de una persona (luego tienes que pasarte la vida calculando y actualizando la edad). Es mejor guardar la fecha de nacimiento y calcular la edad **solamente donde y cuando la necesites**.